# android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY is not working in broadcast receiver, what to do in broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, action, broadcast, receiver

manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryFullReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcastreceiver:

```
public class BatteryFullReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      String intentAction = intent.getAction();
//      if(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY.equalsIgnoreCase(intentAction)){
            Toast.makeText (context, "Battery Full", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            Speaker.tts.speak("Battery full ,you can disconnect the usb now", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);       
        }
//  }

}
```

i tried with battery low and that works.but Battery ok is not working. sometimes i used those code that's why i use comment for checking.but nothing is working.please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misspelled the intent action:
`android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY`

There's a full example in the docs http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#DetermineChargeState

Comment: i tried with both  android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY and android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY but android didn't firing that event at all.